# If someone denies my friend request, will it be deleted from my activity log?

Tags: facebook

Thought I sent a friend request to someone but it is not in my activity log. I don’t want to send a second friend request if my first one is declined.

Comment: Hopefully if the person didn't accept or reject your request it will automatically delete from log.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can deny a friend request, only ignore it. So if the person ignores your request, it is the equivalent of denying it, and you don't get notified.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a friend request, you can confirm request or delete request. If the person deletes your friend request, then it disapears from your activity log. Therefore the person has probably denied your friend request.